# WPF ListBox ItemTemplate: How to make contents fill available space?

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemtemplate

I have set my `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to something like below

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Args}" />
            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Height="10" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The result is

[image]

How can I make the `StackPanel` fill the entire width of the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, Set the [HorizontalContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx) property of the Listbox to Stretch.